# Weird behavior with Bash

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I recently changed my `.bashrc` and tweaked how my PS1 looks, but now it has a very weird problem. Before the end of the line in terminal (about 2 3rds of the way in) it jumps back to the begining of the line like so:

```
e before itarcath@Highgate][~/.gconf/apps/gedit-2/preferences] how long can a command b
```

My first thought was that it wasn't getting the terminal size properly but `tput cols` returns the correct value.

My.bashrc:
http://github.com/Arcath/.Files/blob/master/dotfiles/.bashrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed `\[` and `\]` around the variables for colours, this commit shows my fix:

http://github.com/Arcath/.Files/commit/26527f678073e1b52449326521e98ebc8f3e47ac

Comment: The `readline` library also accepts SOH (`\x01`) and STX (`\x02`) control characters -- useful in other programs (such as Python) which have customizable prompts but not `\[`.